# PHP CAST-256 mcrypt output differs

Tags: php, encryption, cryptography, mcrypt

I am attempting to encrypt a string using CAST256 and CBC, via the PHP function `mcrypt_encrypt`. I am using the key `test` with the input `test`, which produces the following code:

```
mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_CAST_256, 'test', 'test', MCRYPT_MODE_CBC);
```

The base64 encoded version of this produces (on PHP version 5.5.12):

```
DaypOCFVfoI8ghemj0ZkEg==
```

However, I am comparing my output against the tool on http://www.tools4noobs.com/online_tools/encrypt/, and my output differs significantly; the site output using the aforementioned cipher, mode, key, and data is the following:

```
eIKnQGAhjsGh+11XZsA2Lg==
```

Decrypting each string using the opposite tool (i.e. the site output decrypted with PHP, and the PHP output decrypted via the site) gives the following output:

```
DUCD000000000000 (site output)
DUCD000000000000 (PHP output)
```

However, decrypting using the same medium as the string was encrypted with gives the input data ('test').

My question is, **is there a reason for this difference, such as omission of IV when encrypting/decrypting or a misuse of the PHP mcrypt_decrypt function?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is most likely a bug in libmcrypt's cast-256 module, and the site that you've linked seems to be affected by it.

I get the same output as you do on your local machine and the [RFC2612](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2612.txt) test vectors also pass on mine, so don't worry - it's not a mistake on your part, nor is something broken on your end.

I do however have to say that you should never encrypt without using an IV and a proper encryption key ('test' is not a proper key). You should also use a more proven algorithm like AES.